# What is the significance of % in Python

Tags: python

I'm brand new to programming languages and brand new to Python.

I'm still having trouble understanding the significance of %, even though I've read 3 short tutorials that explain it.

Can someone break down what % is doing exactly in this code?

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print n, "=", x, "*", n/x
```

Comment: It's the modulo operator.  It returns the remainder of division.

Comment: Have you run it and observed the result? Also, play with this in the interpreter.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems like a perfectly reasonable and clear question from a novice programmer.

Comment: easily researchable through google

Answer (score 4):

For numbers it returns the remainder of division (as squiguy pointed out).

10 / 3 is 3 with a remainder of 1.

So `10 % 3 == 1`.

---

It's most common use is to check for divisibility.  For example, in that loop it checks if n is divisible by x.  For example it can be use to do something every n<sup>th</sup> time.

```
for i in range(1, 10):
   if i % 3 == 0:
       print "I love cats and dogs"
   else:
       print "I love cats"
```

Outputs,

```
I love cats
I love cats
I love cats and dogs
I love cats
I love cats
I love cats and dogs
I love cats
I love cats
I love cats and dogs
```

Answer (score 1):

The % operator in this case is the [Modulo operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

As explained in the spec:

> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. A zero right argument raises the ZeroDivisionError exception. The arguments may be floating point numbers, e.g., 3.14%0.7 equals 0.34 (since 3.14 equals 4*0.7 + 0.34.) The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly smaller than the absolute value of the second operand

In this case, you are finding the remainder in the division `n / x`

Your code sample iterates from `n=2` to `n=9`.  For each `n`, the inner loop checks for all divisors of `n` that are greater than 1.  For each divisor, it prints out a line showing a factorization of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

For numbers, it's the modulus operator.  For strings, it's the "string interpolation" (or "string formatting") operator.

The specific idiom `if n % x == 0:` in the code corresponds to a divisibility test.  In other words, it will result in `True` if n is divisible by x (i.e. the remainder of the division `n / x` is 0).  Or, if you want, n is a multiple of x (there is some integer y such that x * y == n).

To explain it better, let's analyze the inner iteration when `n` (in the outer one) is 6.  It would be equivalent to:

```
for x in range(2, 6):
    if 6 % x == 0:
        print n, "=", x, "*", n/x
```

With an execution trace:

```
x   6 % x  6 % x == 0    6 / x     Output
--  -----  ----------  ----------  ------
2     0       True         3       6 = 2 * 3
3     0       True         2       6 = 3 * 2
4     2       False    Irrelevant  <none>
5     1       False    Irrelevant  <none>
```

You can go on and try with other values of `n`.  Or all 9 of them.  You will see that, like 6, 8 is an interesting case too.  Even slightly more so.

Answer (score 0):

% is the modulus operator: it will return the remainder of what is basically an integer division operation. `5 % 2 = 1`, `5 % 5 = 0`, etc. In regular integer math, all results are rounded down, so 5 / 2 would return 2, even though two fits into five 2.5 times. Of course 0 is a special case and has undefined behavior in most languages.

Comment: If whoever voted down this answer would like to make a comment as to why, I would greatly appreciate it. Am I incorrect?

Comment: If I had to guess at a reason for the downvote, the last sentence is  ambiguous. But try not to sweat uncommented downvotes 'round these parts (yes, it can be irksome, but so it goes).

Answer (score -1):

In arithmetic, if you are using the set of real numbers (or the rational numbers), and you divide, say, `1/2`, you can get `0.5` as the answer. Now, if you constrain yourself to only using the integers, `1/2` would return `0`, because, in the integers, `1` is not divisible by `2`. One way of doing integer division, then, would be to perform long division, store the integer portion of the result as the result of the integer division, and as to not lose any data, store also the remainder, which is what the `%` operator returns.

In Python, when you do standard division `/`, you are actually doing floating point division (so fractions can be represented), and hence `1/2 = 0.5`. Now, if you used integer division `//`, then `1//2 = 0`. To obtain this value, python simply performs standard division, and takes the floor of the result. If you were to manually write out the division algorithm on paper, you'd notice that this division has a remainder of `1`. The modulus `%` operator simply returns this remainder.

So, `1/2 = 0.5`, `1//2 = 0`, and `1%2 = 1`.

In other words, `%` returns the same remainder that you would obtain when doing long division.

```
     _0_ <-- result of (1//2)
   2| 1
     -0
     ---
      1 <- remainder, result of (1 % 2)
```

Comment: "`1/2` would return `0`, because `2` can only divide `1` zero times" - I'm not sure I understand what that means.

Comment: See the edit I made, explaining it in the context of a long-division problem. That statement means that 1 is not divisible by 2, if you can only use integer numbers to express your result. And yes, // is a real thing, [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)